# How to delete LinkedIn account

Tags: linkedin, delete

I want to delete my account on LinkedIn, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From LinkedIn [Help page](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/63/close-your-linkedin-account?lang=en):

> Closing your account will delete any recommendations or endorsements you've given or received, plus your messages and connections.

> To close your LinkedIn account from the **Settings & Privacy** page:
>
> 1. Click the  **Me** icon at top of your LinkedIn homepage.
> 2. Select **Settings & Privacy** from the dropdown.
> 3. Under **Account management** section of the **Account preferences** section, click  **Change** next to **Close account**.
> 4. Check the reason for closing your account and click **Next**.
> 5. Enter your account password and click **Close account**.